# This exception was thrown because the response has a status code of 404 and RequestOptions.validateStatus was configured to throw for this status code

Tags: php, flutter, dart, dio

In flutter I tried to POST data using the DIO package, I posted some data:

```
final response = await dio.post(
      "127.0.0.1/toko_grosir_api/create.php",
      data: {
        'name': '${event.product.nameProduct}',
        'price': '${event.product.priceProduct}',
        'desc': '${event.product.descProduct}',
        'stock': '${event.product.stockProduct}',
        'date': '${event.product.dateProduct}',
        'category': '${event.product.categoryProduct}'
      },
      options: Options(
        contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType,
      ),
    );
```

and I am trying to receive data using PHP as Rest API with the following code:

```
$nameProd = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
$priceProd = isset($_POST['price']) ? $_POST['price'] : null;
$descProd = isset($_POST['desc']) ? $_POST['desc'] : null;
$stockProd = isset($_POST['stock']) ? $_POST['stock'] : null;
$dateProd = isset($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : null;
$categoryProd = isset($_POST['category']) ? $_POST['category'] : null;
```

However, it displays an error when POSTing the data as like this:

> This exception was thrown because the response has a status code of
> 404 and RequestOptions.validateStatus was configured to throw for this
> status code. The status code of 404 has the following meaning: "Client
> error - the request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled" Read
> more about status codes at
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status In order to
> resolve this exception you typically have either to verify and fix
> your request code or you have to fix the server code.

I've tried the PHP rest API using postman and it worked according to the variables needed in the rest API, what's wrong with with my code?

Comment: 404 is page not found, not bad syntax. That means it can't find `127.0.0.1/toko_grosir_api/create.php`. I don't know if you need a schema in front of `127.0.0.1` so that it's looking for `http://127.0.0.1` instead of `http://127.0.0.1/(..otherstuffmaybehere/)127.0.0.1`